# Regular Expression for length that validate word with length but not email

Tags: regex, validation

I need a regular expression to validate a large text (max 2000 characters), it should work as follows:

Say n=20

1. If there is any word in the text with letters greater than n, it will not validate the whole text.
2. If there is an email in the text say emailaddress@emailserver.com, then it should ignore that.
3. If the email address is like 123456789012345678901@email.com (as in this case n > 20), it will not validate the whole text.

I'm using `^(?!.*\S{10}).*$` as of now but it does not validate the email.

I racked my brain for a good ten minutes with no luck, I think it must have been some syntax I have yet to learn.

All suggestions would be greatly appreciated, many thanks!

Comment: You want email addresses that run less than 20 characters?

Comment: it will validate emailaddress@emailserver.com but not 123456789012345678901@email.com

Comment: try: \b\w{1,20}\b@\w+\.\w+

Comment: this regex is validating only emails now, not the other words. for eg

Comment: this regex is validating only emails now, not the other words. for eg
n=5
1. a, ab, abc, abcd, abcde (valid)
2. abcdef, abcdefg, ..... (invalid)
3. abcd@email.com (valid)
4. abcdef@email.com (invalid)

Comment: If you can include a screenshot of your desired validation from your paragraph/text in the question perhaps it would be clearer. Try refactoring your question.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following pattern:

```
\b[^\s@]{30,}\b
```

- This pattern does not allow a word to be longer than 30 characters
- It will handle e-mail addresses as two words (one word before and one word after the `@`.

```js
var n = 30;
// doubly escaped slashes and global search (g)
var regex = new RegExp('\\b[^\\s@]{' + n + ',}\\b', 'g');
var text = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;

var match = text.match(regex);
if(match) {
  console.log("Document contains a value with over " + n + " characters.");
  console.log(match);
}
else {
  console.log("Document does not contain a value with over " + n + " characters.");
}
```

```html
<div id="text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
  sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
  et accusametjustoduodoloreseterebumstet@clita.kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla
  facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
</div>
```